# Regex to get text between chapters titles in upper-case

Tags: regex, text-extraction, pcre2

I am trying to extract chapters/sections for txt files whose were generated using pdftotext on portuguese Lawsuits documents.
Initially I tried this regex to, at least, get each chapter title:

```
^[A-Z\s\d\W]+$
```

Apparently it had worked for this example: https://regex101.com/r/FQKsy4/1

But, for this one: https://regex101.com/r/BEO55p/3

I got some non titles like those matches:

[image]

[image]

So, how can I get not only each chapter/section title but each content of them too?

I tried a regex to get each chapter and its content but not worked very well in some documents

Comment: What denotes the starting of a section? Like this? `^[^\S\n]*[A-Z][^a-z]*(?:\n(?![^\S\n]*[A-Z][^a-z\n]*$).*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/W3CkdI/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes. Is there is possible now to divide in titles and contents?

Comment: @celsowm Also see [if this one helps](https://regex101.com/r/3oASM4/1) (I was playing with your question too at the moment)

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/E8crao/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah ! Post as an answer so I can give you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using 2 capture groups:

```
^[^\S\n]*([A-Z][^a-z]*)((?:\n(?![^\S\n]*[A-Z][^a-z\n]*$).*)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\n]*` Match optional spaces without newlines
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][^a-z]*` Match a single uppercase char followed by any char except a lowercase a-z
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\n(?![^\S\n]*[A-Z][^a-z\n]*$).*)*` Optionally repeat matching all lines that do not start with a title like pattern
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpaH4F/1)

A bit more pcre like approach:

```
^\h*([A-Z][^a-z]*)((?>\R(?!\h*[A-Z][^a-z\r\n]*$).*)*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yTLGXj/1)